# Database design for steps

Tags: c#, sql, database-design

I want to design a database that tracks a product development cycle.

It has 4 steps

> 1. in queue
> 2. Processed
> 3. In transit
> 4. Delivered

In Queue means it arrived at the depot. 
Porcessed means it was packaged in fancy packaging material and inspected for any flaws
In Transit means its currently in a van going to the client
Delivered means it was delivered to the client.

I know there is an otiopn where i would have

```
tblProducts
==========
idProduct
Description
IdStatus 

Status
======
Id
Status
```

However im wondering if there is a better option, perhaps a type of cascading style with nulls in them like this

```
Products
========
IdProduct
Description


Step1
=====
Id
IdProduct
Step2 - nullable

Step2
=====
Id
Step3 - nullable


Step3
=======
Id
Step4 - nullable
```

For example if step1 is complete it would have a step1,If step2 is completed then it would have a step2.

Im wondering which is more correct, the first one i can cause various database inconsistency errors..

Im unable to add tags because autocomplete doesnt work for me.Please somebody add sql database design.

After some research i found the following link to be very helpful in solving my problem.
Seems my problem is commonly reffered to as Graph Algorithms

http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on the actual use.

E.g., you might want to create an extra entity called Transition. This table could contain a row for each allowed transition between steps. This would allow you to add more steps, migrate products from one flow to another and remove steps.

The product would refer to its current step and to move to the next step a procedure could query the Transition table for allowed next steps and update the product to the next step.

The procedure could also take care of validating the transition based on the current step and the status of the product.

Comment: could you pleaes draw something so i can confirm im on the same page as you thx :D

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact enough to have two tables. One with step types e.g 1= queued,  2= in transit etc.

This makes the design simple but also stable. it reduces data duplication.

On the products table you add a column named StepId.  The stepid equals a value from you step table (described above).

This also allows you to add multiple steps quickly - by simply adding a row instead of a table.

You can also quickly group your data yo show each step.

If this is not clear please let me know and I will make a short example for you.

Comment: you should always make example cuz alot of people will read this and some might not understand.I m thinking the exact thing as you.

Comment: my laptop is not around.  That's why I thought I should post it but then make the sample later.